# Low Voltage LED Runway lights Part 2

Tags: low-voltage

1. I will use 10 g 2 strand  direct bury low voltage wire

I believe  that I need to run a loop and I am considering adding another 600 watt transformer to the opposite side of the runway that will turn on at the same time.

Total number of lights is 40 and each DC Edison fixture bulb is 7 watts.

Is there a better way to achieve constant voltage in the loop by using a Constant Current LED driver or Isolation transformer.

The fact that my o e transformer works leads me to believe this is not an impossible task.

Suggestions,  corrections comments any help is,welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not clear from your description what the proposed configuration is; for this kind of installation it would be far preferable to put all the LEDs in series and use a constant current driver.  However that may result in an unacceptably high DC voltage and so you might prefer to run several loops, which would add some resilience against a single-point failure.

Comment: BTW the reason your first question was closed is not because ‘we’ want to make life awkward for you but to make the information (details of both the question and the answer) accessible for future readers.  To that end, it’s good to have all the relevant information in the question rather than in follow-on comments and similarly the answer should be complete and concise.

Comment: I want to create a 2000 ft loop with twenty  7 W DC only lights on each side of the runway. I have reviewed the Constant Current LED drivers but I AM NOT SURE WHERE IN THE LOOP CIRCUIT TO PUT THE DRIVER?  HOW many Constant Current Drivers are needed?  The loop will in series but adding isolation transformers (like 6.6 amp at major airports) is beyond my knowledge base. I thought I might consult Subject matter experts to pprevent a lot of trial and error or LED Runaway Heat issues. I have a very rudimentary understanding and need help.

Comment: I understand and I simply did not understand the Rules of Engagement. I do appreciate the consideration of this problem by experts whose basic fund of knowledge far exceeds mine. Ask me a detailed question about trauma or serious bodily injury.

Comment: @Hermannator we don't care about grammar XD What's important is to put all the information you have in the question (not in comments), so we know what you're talking about. You can edit your question (don't forget to copy the stuff you said in the comments of the other question). Also we'll need a link for the bulbs, it would be nice if there was a product description for the bulb to know on what range of voltage it works. Also your transformer outputs AC but you say bulbs are DC so there are some details missing

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Voltage-Equivalent-12volt-Battery-Interior-Lighting/dp/B07MCGH7N4/ref=mp_s_a_1_3?crid=2SQX96C8RUNU1&keywords=7%2Bw%2Bdc%2Bbulbs&qid=1703362875&sprefix=%2Caps%2C172&sr=8-3&th=1&psc=1

Comment: 10awg wire will give around 1 ohm per 1000ft, so 2 ohms or 4 ohms total depending on whether your 2000ft is loop length or 2000ft out and 2000ft return.  40 x 7W is 280W total so at 24V the current will be 11.7A.  Here it gets a little messy because each lamp down the line will see a slightly lower voltage and will therefore draw more current, so the voltage drop will be worse than 11.7A x 2 ohms = 23.4V.  As you can see the lamps at the far end will see almost no voltage.  Feeding power from both ends would help but the resistive losses would still be significant.

Comment: @Frog - Hi, This question has now been voted closed as a duplicate of the OP's [earlier question](/q/695235), which had much less info *there* when you answered the question *here*. || I think that your answer also applies to the OP's improved version of that earlier question. I plan to merge the two questions, so that your answer (& comments) will move to that (now improved) earlier question that I linked. This way, there is just one question instead of two which are effectively duplicates. || If you have any strong objections to your answer moving to that question, please reply asap. Thanks.

Comment: All good, do your thing :-) have a splendid Christmas.